# net core MVC not load javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a .net core MVC application that have a page that do an ajax call using jQuery that return a cshtml with a `<script>` reference.

When I try to call some of the function inside the script, the error `<function name> is not defined` is trigger.

At the end of the _Layout.cshtml page I have `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`.

This is the function that load the html page:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/controller/method",
        data: {},
        method: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 300000000
    }).done(function(htmlPage){
    var fragment = document.createElement('div');
    fragment.innerHTML = paginaHtml;
    ej.base.append(fragment.children, document.getElementById('containerGerarchiaAgenti'), true);

      setTimeout(function () {
         // this function is inside the js file that is in the htmlPage
         initPageGerarchiaAgenti();
     });
})
```

Inside the .cshtml page I have tried to include the js file in many ways:

- `@section Scripts { <script type=xx src=xx> }`
- directly on page with `<script type=xx src=xx>`
- inside the first @{ --> `@{ @section Scripts { <script type=xx src=xx> } }`

but nothing works.

How can I make this thing works?

Comment: could be a timing issue.  Hard to say as this ajax call doesn't seem to do anything with the returned page and you've left out some code that defines variables you are using.  Consider when this .ajax call is made.  Most jQuery code will run when the page loads and set certain event handlers.

Comment: also if a JS is in the .appended content it will not run... (scripts run when the full page loads or when a specific event handler calls it...)  append() does not trigger a page load, or a $. page ready state for jQuery.